# Selecting rows by strings through pandas columns (with conditions)

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to select rows that contains specific words from two different lists.
The relationships between the two lists is:

- at least one of item from list2 AND at least one of item from list1,

looking for them in two different columns (at least one of the two columns should contain these terms).
So I need always at least one item from list2 + eventually one item from list1 in the same column or in the two columns.

For example

```
list1=['pianta','albero','muro']
list2=['parco','giardino','foresta','bosco']
```

Original dataset

```
Luogo                          Posto                + other columns
C'era una pianta               giardino                   ...
Non c'è niente da fare         a casa mia                 ...
Ho una pianta sul balcone      Che ora è?                 ...
Non ricordo che giorno è       Vorrei andare al parco     ...
```

Expected output:

```
Luogo                          Posto                + other columns
C'era una pianta               giardino                   ...
```

I have tried with this code:

```
df1=df[df[['Luogo','Posto']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list1))).any(1) & df[['Luogo','Posto']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list2)))]
```

but it is not giving me the expected output. Could you please have a look at it and tell me how to improve it to get that result?

Many thanks

Comment: Why `Non ricordo che giorno è ` is kept? it does not contain any words in the lists

Comment: I need to keep the row if at least it contains an element from list2 (s in this case it contains parco)

Comment: So you can simply use:
`df[df[['Luogo','Posto']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list2))).any(1)]`

Comment: @DavideBrex, I checked the output. I was wrong as I need to consider both the lists, by following this condition: at least one of item from `list2` AND at least one of item from `list1`. So I need to filter the rows based on at least one element from `list2` and at least one item from `list1`. Sorry for the confusion. I updated the expected output. If you have a solution, I would suggest to put as answer so I can select it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate both the text columns and check if atlest one item of `list1` and one item of `list2` appear in the concatenated string.

```
df[df['Luogo'].str.cat(df['Posto'], sep=" ").apply(lambda x: any([y in x for y in list1]) and any([y in x for y in list2]))]
```